# Elastic search document count

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, count

I am having a Elastic search running 2.2 version. I have created index and loaded sample documents. I found some problem in it.  When i give

```
GET index/type/_count
```

I am getting the correct answer

```
{
   "count": 9998,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   }
}
```

But when i see the things using `http://IP:9200/_cat/indices?v`

```
health status index pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size     
yellow open   index  5   1      79978            0     32.1mb         32.1mb
```

Where docs.count : 79978. Which is wrong.

**Why i am seeing docs.count with wrong value**. The exact document count is 9998

Comment: you may have docs in some other type in same index, try GET index/_count to confirm

Comment: {
   "count": 9998,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   }
}   I am getting the same 9998. When i  give GET index/_count

Comment: Do you have fields with `nested` type in your mapping?

Comment: @Val, Yes i am having

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`GET index/type/_count` will return the top-level document count.

`docs.count` in `_cat/indices` returns the count of all documents, including artificial documents that have been created for nested fields.

That's why you see a difference:

- The former count (i.e. 9998) will tell you how many **Elasticsearch documents** are in your index, i.e. how many you have indexed.
- The latter count (i.e. 79978) will tell you how many **Lucene documents** are in your index.

So if one ES document contain a nested field with 5 sub-elements, you'll see 1 ES document, but 6 Lucene documents. Judging by the counts, each of your ES document has between 7 and 8 nested elements within it.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @youhans yes [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html)