# Why there are 20 documents diff (cat vs count)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to compare results of `count` and `cat` for the amount of documents and I'm getting different results:

`GET /my_index/_count` gives:

```json
{
  "count": 4020199,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

And `GET /_cat/indices` gives:

```
green open my_index 53IuNvZ1T4W_8u1U4bf7kb 1 1 8040418 0 27gb 13.5gb
```

When we compare the quantities we get that:

```
8040418 - 4020199 * 2 (one replica) = 20
```

Note: I used `refresh` command and there is no change.

So where are that 20 loss documents ?

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36857604/4604579 (hint: you have twenty nested documents)

Comment: Thanks, if I understand the answer there are 10 nested documents (10*2 (replica) = 20), am I right ? (insead of 20 nested documents as you wrote) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, 10 is right