# docs.count and match all query results for a given index do not match

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The result for `curl -k 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,docs.count&format=json'  | grep test_index`:

```json
...
   {
      "index":"test_index",
      "docs.count":"72365"
   },
...
```

and a `match_all` query on the same index (when executing from python REPPL) are different:

```json
query='{"query":{"match_all":{}}, "size":10000}'
...
{'_shards': {'failed': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'successful': 3, 'total': 3},
```

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36857604/4604579. `docs.count` includes nested documents count, while match_all returns the count of top-level documents